# Assign array values to PHP variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have some code which checks to see whether a certain variable is an array.  If it is, I would like to assign all the array values to a single, comma-separated PHP variable.  Here is the code:

```
if (is_array($value)) {         
    //Need to assign the array variables to the PHP variable $files, but how?
    $postdata.=$files;          
} else {
    $postdata.=$value;
}
```

I have tried to use `$files = print_r(array_values($value));` but it does not seem to work for me.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: `$postdata .= implode(", ", $files);` perhaps?

Comment: Check out [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: I was just writing that. @bwoebi

Comment: sounds like you want implode()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$string = implode(',', $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this line:    `$files= implode(',', $value);`

Comment: lol, I hate it when I leave SO page too long before posting an answer, so that my answer looks exactly as if I copied someone who posted the correct answer a fews mins before!

Comment: the quick and the dead :-0\